# Best half mini PCI-E (laptop) Wireless card

Tags: wireless

I'm thinking about replacing the wireless card on my laptop (an atheros ar9285) because it is slow.

What are the best half mini PCI-E 802.11n cards with 300 Mbps max speed and two antennas?

I wan't one that works well with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I get the cheapest one I can find, look at the technical details, and check the chip for compatibility.

http://linuxwireless.org/

You can also google search the chip set and see if people are having problems or not on the major forums (Ubuntu, Debian, and Fedora). Generally the driver is in the kernel, so more dependent on kernel then distribution.

Comment: did you ever replace the card?  I'm looking to also replace my card but dont know where to start.  Im considering an Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6230